# Inserting into a HashTable

Tags: c++, list, vector, hashtable

So, I'm really at a lost here. I'm having a really difficult time trying to insert a item into a hash table, `insert(const Entry& e)` I posted my most recent attempt below, I know it's not much, but as of now it's all I got. Any push in the right direction is very appreciated.
My structure and class definition should be fine as is.

Currently getting,

> hTable.cc: In member function ‘void HT::insert(const Entry&)’:
>
> hTable.cc:38:19: error: no match for ‘operator=’

Error is happening when I do, `hTable[hashVal] = new Entry(e);`

and

> hTable.cc:37:57:   required from here
>
> /usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h:234:30: error: expression cannot be
>
> used as a function
>
> { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }

Second error is coming from the same line where I use `find_if()`, I assume it has to do with how I used `hashVal`? I did look up `find_if()`, but a lot of the explanations didn't make much sense to me.

Below is my structure, for the entry in the table (Entry.h)

```
#ifndef H_ENTRY
#define H_ENTRY

#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define ID_SZ      3    // size of key
#define ITEM_SZ    24   // max size for item description 
#define TBL_SZ     31   // default size for hash table

struct Entry {
    string key,   // key
           desc;  // description
    unsigned num; // no of copies

    //constructor
    Entry ( const string& k = "", const string& d = "",
        const unsigned& n = 0 ) : key ( k ), desc ( d ),
        num ( n ) { }
};
#endif
```

Below is my class definition for my hash table (hTable.h)

```
#include "Entry.h"
#ifndef H_HASH_TABLE
#define H_HASH_TABLE

#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

class HT {
public:
    HT ( const unsigned& = TBL_SZ );   // constructor
    ~HT ( );                           // destructor
    void insert ( const Entry& );      // inserts item in hash table
private:
    unsigned hsize;                    // size of hash table
    vector < list < Entry > >  hTable; // hash table
    vector < Entry* > pTable;          // ptr table
    int hash ( const string& );        // hash function
};
#endif
```

Below is my hTable.cc, where my problem is.

```
#include "hTable.h"

HT::~HT() {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < hsize; i++)
                        hTable.pop_back();
}
HT::HT(const unsigned& hs) {
        hTable.resize(hs);
        pTable.resize(hs);
}
void HT::insert(const Entry& e) {
//if key already exists, print out message saying so.
//else, insert into hash table
        //also inserts the address of the record (in the hash table) into the pointer table

    int hashVal = hash(e.key);

    if( find_if( hTable.begin(), hTable.end(), hashVal) == hTable.end() )
            hTable[hashVal] = new Entry(e);
    else
            cout << "\ntemp message\n";

}
```

Comment: do you get any error messages that tell you it's not working right? that might help us. and keep trying, you'll get it!

Comment: Went in and added the error messages I was getting!

Comment: You have more problems than just the `insert()` function. You have major bugs all over the place, such as uninitialized class members that are being used in the destructor, when there's no need to use them in the destructor in the first place.

Comment: But since the hash table is being implemented as a vector of list containers, don't I need to free all memory for the list containers and free the memory for the vector containers (my hash table and pointer table)?

Comment: It is not necessary to manually remove anything from a container. Its destructor will take care of it. The only time it is necessary to do anything would be with container of pointers to objects allocated in dynamic scope. But in that case, one should use `std::shared_ptr`, which will do it for you, anyway. Modern C++ code almost never needs to use `new` and `delete`, with the containers taking care of everything.

Comment: Where else are these major bugs aside from the destructor? My hands are pretty tied on this, I'm not able to change anything from Entry.h or hTable.h, so I would assume they are fine?

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in the code:

1. If the hash table does not allow duplicated entries. There's no need to declare the `hTable` as `vector < list< Entry > >`. `vector< Entry >` satisfies the requirement. If the declaration of `hTable` cannot be changed, the code should be `hTable[hashVal].push_back( e );`
2. The copy assignment and copy constructor of `Entry` need to be defined explicitly.
3. The output of hash value need to be in the range of the size of the hash table or the function `insert` need to check whether the hash value is in the range.
4. `find_if` needs a condition function or functor. In your code, it would be.

```
class CheckKey {
public: 
    CheckKey(const string& key) : _key(hash(key)) {};
    bool operator==(Entry const& e) {
        return hash(e.key) == _key;
    }
private:
    int hash(const string&) {...};
    int _key;
};

void HT::Insert(const Entry& e) { 
    CheckKey chk(e.key);
    vector< list< Entry > >::iterator itfind = find_if(hTable.begin(), hTable.end(), chk);

    if(itfind!=hTable.end() && find->empty()) {
        itfind->push_back(e);
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `hash()` will return a value between 0 and table size - 1.
What's the copy constructor used for here? As far as I know, I shouldn't need one for this.

Comment: The copy constructor and copy assignment is used to assign the <code>Entry e</code> into the hash table <code>hTable</code>.

Comment: I don't think I'm allowed to write any more methods/constructors/etc.. than what was provided in the definition of the hTable class.

Comment: The structure `Entry` needs the copy constructor and copy assignment since the explicit use of assignment and copy create in your code.

Comment: `hTable[hashVal] = new Entry(e);`